# Python module issue - "ModuleNotFoundError" and "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to run a simple python script using the `beautifulsoup4` module.

However, when I run the .py file, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError.`
When I try to `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` I get `Requirement already satisfied`.

I've tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling [with and without `sudo`];
- `easy_install beautifulsoup4`;
- checking the paths with `which python3`; and
- all of the above in python2.7

Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: Where is the python script? Please provide your code so we can check out where you might've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

check the link: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Answer (score -1):

Since you used *pip3 install module* run your script with **python3 script.py**